# Fastest and safest way to reduce column sizes in large table?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that has **53,245,114 rows**. This InnoDB table is currently **26.3 GiB**.

I believe the large size is attributed to the size I set some of the columns.

For example, column `name` is set to `VARCHAR 200` when it should be set to `VARCHAR 80`. I have a few other columns similarly set to `VARCHAR 200` which need to be reduced.

What is the fastest and safest way to accomplish this? I have read that doing an `INSERT INTO` a new table is potentially the best approach. Would this be the case?

Some misc information:

[image]

Comment: 'I believe the large size is attributed to the size I set some of the columns' - I don't you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#:~:text=The%20effective%20maximum%20number%20of,is%20shared%20among%20all%20columns.

Comment: `VARCHAR` columns require _length_ + 1 bytes for strings less than 255 characters, where _length_ is the actual length of the stored data. Changing the _defined_ size of the column will have little effect on the storage requirement.

Comment: Appreciate the lesson guys! I'll investigate other alternative methods!